# Why would the Context Lookup Fail for this Specific JMS Message Queue in Glassfish?

Tags: glassfish, jndi, message-driven-bean

I have a message queue in Glassfish with a name like "String.String.etc".  Whenever I try to send a message to that MQ, I get the following error message:

> Lookup failed for 'java:comp/env/[MQ Name]' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming}

I have another JMS Queue with the name of "jms/Beta".  I don't get this problem for that MQ.  Why would the first mentioned MQ cause the Context lookup to fail, but not the second one?

Answer (score 0):

In a Java EE application, JMS administered objects are normally placed in the **jms** naming subcontext.

I think GF absolutely needs the jms part before the JMS Queue.

Cheers,
Eugene.

Comment: Nope.  You're wrong, because I created a JMS Queue with the JNDI Name of "jms/Queue" and still got the same problem.

Comment: @user919860 sorry to hear, can you post the code of how you create the Queue (asadmin I suppose) and the code that tries to get that queue then?